# Is it wrong to say "so verb that" or "so f**king verb that"?

Tags: grammar

1. × My smartphone so sucks that it takes about a minute to load a webpage
2. ✓ My smartphone sucks so much that it takes about a minute to load a webpage.
3. × The audio so fucking sucks that it can't even pronounce/play a word correctly.
4. ✓ The audio sucks so fucking bad that it can't even pronounce/play a word correctly.

A native English speaker once told me that sentence 1 and 2 are wrong and should be rewritten as 2 and 4, but I actually have seen "so" and "so fucking" can be used to modify "verbs" for emphasis, as in 1 and 3.

Are 1 and 3 really wrong even in colloquial English?
I seem to have heard that "so verb" and "so fucking verb" is often used among young people.

Other similar examples I found on the internet.

5. I so love you that I want to marry you.
6. The language and mindset of Econ101 so pervades public debate that it shapes the way that we all think about the economy.
7. They so hate that color

Comment: The f-word is completely irrelevant grammatically here.

Answer (score 4):

Use of 'so' before a verb, to emphasise the verb action's extent, is normal and correct.

> For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever
>   believes in him should not perish but have eternal life. Bible, John
>   3:16
>
> (with a verb): We were so looking forward to meeting your family.

[So (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/so_1)

Comment: So do you think 1 and 3 sound natural and grammatically correct?

Comment: They don't sound normal to me, but slang and use of profanity tends to mutate and evolve rapidly with each generation; it also tends to be highly regional. I am 38 and no longer live in an English-speaking country, and it may well be that younger people or people in other regions use it in this way more commonly.

Comment: @SinK They might be grammatically correct, but they do not sound natural. IME in British English, use of the form "so [verb]" feels archaic/formal/posh, and it's very jarring to use it with the very informal "sucks".

Comment: Oh dear! What's wrong with 'posh', whatever that means?